# Comparing list values

Tags: python, list

How do I modify this code to allow me to use a `last_coordinates` list to compare with the current `coordinates` list, so that I could call a method like `activate()` when there is a difference in a value between those two lists?

```
HOST = '59.191.193.59'
PORT = 5555

coordinates = []

def connect():   
    globals()['client_socket'] = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((HOST,PORT))

def update_coordinates():
    screen_width = 0
    screen_height = 0
    while True:
        try:
            client_socket.send("loc\n")
            data = client_socket.recv(8192)
        except:
            connect();
            continue;

        globals()['coordinates'] = data.split()

        if(not(coordinates[-1] == "eom" and coordinates[0] == "start")):
            continue

        if (screen_width != int(coordinates[2])):
        screen_width = int(coordinates[2])
                screen_height = int(coordinates[3])
        return

Thread(target=update_coordinates).start()
connect()
update_coordinates()
while True:
    #compare new and previous coordinates then activate method?
    activate()
```

Comment: What does network/socket code have to do with the question?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `globals()` ?

Comment: Use `globals coordinates` before assigning to it instead of `globals()['coordinates']`, or use `coordinates[:] = data.split()` to avoid the local vs. global assignment issue altogether.

Comment: You don't *have* a `last_coordinates` list in your code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i want to implement it to this code

Comment: @JonClements its running as a thread

Comment: @Tichodroma returning values from a server

Comment: @Edward: You are running this is *threads*?! You'll have many more problems accessing a global list then. In any case, `globals()` will not protect you from those problems and won't behave any different than using `global coordinates` would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize last_coordinates at module scope

```
last_coordinates = ['start', 0, 0]
```

Later after you receive your data, add something like the following code:

```
globals()['coordinates'] = data.split()
if last_coordinates[0] != coordinates[0] or \
   last_coordinates[1] != coordinates[1] or \
   last_coordinates[2] != coordinates[2]:
   # Do something useful here

# this line copies your coordinates into last_coordinates
last_coordinates = coordinates[:]
```

There are other problems with your code, as others have also pointed out in the comments. E.g. the first line in the above fragment could better be rewritten as:

```
 global coordinates
 coordinates = data.split()
```

But then you may still have problems with threading.